# How to insert image in database

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO Employees (Id, Name, Photo) 
SELECT 10, 'John', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Users\mine\Desktop\2.jpg', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(50) not null,
    Photo varbinary(max) not null
)
```

Iam using the above code but while executing this it throws an error like

Cannot bulk load because the file `"C:\Users\mine\Desktop\2.jpg"` could not be opened. Operating **system error code 3**(The system cannot find the path specified.).

Iam using sql server2008r2
please resolve this

Comment: Never store images in your database. Even if you can, don't!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please next time if you want to write a code put it in a code format. You can do this by highlighting the code and selecting the '{}' sign from your editor.

For your question are using widows authentication for your SQL Authentication? if so, please try SQL authentication and try again . There is a good explanation that migth help [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/10/29/sql-bulk-copy-error-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied.aspx)

This error is likely due to permission privilage by the account on the file accessed.